# Find link that ends with jpg and replace inside the link

Tags: notepad++

Hy i am trying to find a way to replace all links that have Danish letters inside them and replace those with their html equivalent like this
å -> %E5

eksempel-ikke-beskåret-2-1024x749.jpg

eksempel-ikke-besk%E5ret-2-1024x749.jpg

I am looking for a mysql solution or a string to find and replace in notepad++.
The website is done on WordPress and it does not see the images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to write a function that checks every char in the string.
If it matches a Danish character it would be replaced by its HTML equivalent.

**EDIT**

```
str_replace('Æ', '&AElig;', $link);
```

You would have to adjust the function for every Danish character.

Danish Characters to HTML: http://www.thesauruslex.com/typo/eng/enghtml.htm#da

Comment: Yeah that's what i need help with :)